# addClass() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, addclass

I have a bootstrap button

```
<button onclick="leaveOpen()">TEST</button>
```

It calls a custom function

```
function leaveOpen(){
  $("#rangeDropdown").addClass('open');
  $("#dropdownMenu2").trigger('focus').attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
}(jQuery);
```

Which should affect these elements

```
<div class="dropup mobilewidth mobilebottom" id="rangeDropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle mobilewidth" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
   ...
  </button>
...
</div>
```

This part works

```
$("#dropdownMenu2").trigger('focus').attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
```

but this part doesn't

```
$("#rangeDropdown").addClass('open');
```

When I click the the *TEST* button, the *"dropup mobilewidth mobilebottom"* lights up in the chrome developer tool as if something changed, but the *'open'* class is not added. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure `$("#rangeDropdown")` returns an element(s)?

Comment: Are you sure that the id `rangeDropdown` is unique throught the page?

Comment: Yes I am sure, and yes it is unique. Because the test button blinks the class, I know it identifies it and triggers the addClass function. Plus, other classes can be added, just not 'open'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clearly the issue that the class is added & it's removed.

Probably bootstrap watches on `focus` event and **toggles** the `open` class.
If your handler is before bootstrap:

- you: `open` added
- bootstrap: `open` is toggled

-> result: nothing changes

In the other case the class would be added, but looking at your description that Chrome Dev Tools flashes that something changed it's rather the issue of double changing the `open` class

Comment: You're right! I need to figure out where and why it's toggling. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, it seems to work for me if the button is on the page. This alerts the class attribute after clicking the button:

```js
function leaveOpen(){
  
  $("#rangeDropdown").addClass('open');
  
  alert($("#rangeDropdown").attr('class'));
  
  $("#dropdownMenu2").trigger('focus').attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
  
}(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropup mobilewidth mobilebottom" id="rangeDropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle mobilewidth" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
   ...
  </button>
...
</div>
    
<button onclick="leaveOpen()">TEST</button>
```

Comment: I would tend to agree with Xeon, good chance bootstrap is toggling 'open' class